# Move additional information from product tab under add to cart button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In single product pages, I would like to change the location of "additional information" from tabs, under add to cart button using Woocommerce hooks *(removing the "additional information" tab)*.

I have:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'wc_display_product_attributes', 10 );
```

and: `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button`

**I'm trying:**

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'wc_display_product_attributes', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'woocommerce_product_additional_information' );
```

and

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'wc_display_product_attributes', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 60 );
```

**But it doesn't work.**

How can I move properly "additional information" below add to cart button?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following code will remove additional information tab and add additional information below add to cart:

```
 // Remove additional information tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_additional_information_tab', 100, 1 );
function remove_additional_information_tab( $tabs ) {
    unset($tabs['additional_information']);

    return $tabs;
}

// Add "additional information" after add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'additional_info_under_add_to_cart', 35 );
function additional_info_under_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters( 'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || $product->has_dimensions() ) ) ) {
        wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much!!! LoicTheAztec your code works great and solves my problem!

Comment: is there any way to move additional information after the title  or before price section

Comment: Wow!! That worked like a charm. is there any way to show only some fields.?

Comment: @sanjeevshetty There is [`woocommerce_display_product_attributes` filter hook for  `wc_display_product_attributes()` function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L3440), that should allow you to show only some fields…

Comment: Working perfectly. Upvote from my side.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore